# Eclipse is formatting javadoc tooltips very poorly on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I've been using Eclipse on Windows a lot, and recently started using it on Ubuntu for work.

My problem is, that the Javadoc tool til mostly is unformatted, E.g. `<code>` tags, links, etc. have no effect. Only line chages by `b`, `br` or ,`pre` tags plus bold seems to be rendered. (`pre` don't change font.). See the first example below.

Are there any tweaks I can do, to get something like the second image?

Extra: A fix to the colors, would be also be awesome, but not as important.

Thanks.

---

***What I see now:***
[image: What I see]

***What I'll like to see***

Soruce: http://codeblessyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/2011-07-01_115631.jpg

[image: What I want to see]

Comment: What version of Eclipse? I cannot reproduce that with Juno on Ubuntu 12.4. For me all style tags are applied correctly.

Comment: I'm on Eclipse 3.8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. Are you in 3.8 or 4.2?

Comment: Ok. Anyone out there on 3.8.0 that can tell if they have the problem too?

Comment: I have the same problem. Eclipse 3.8 (from Android's ADT bundle), Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got the same problem with the rendering of HTML inside the tooltips. After some fiddling around I got the solution:

Install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 from the official Ubuntu repositories. It'S used by eclipse (and most likely other GTK applications) to render the HTML, but neither pre-installed on Kubuntu nor listed as a dependency in the eclipse packages.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to test this, as I'm no longer on a Ubuntu workstation. It sounds like a very reasonable solution, so I'll accept this as the answer. **Is there anyone else who can confirm this?**

Comment: This worked for me on my RH/CentOS machine, the package name there is `webkitgtk`

Comment: Worked for me! Arch package name is `webkitgtk2` [installing just `webkitgtk` which currently is the 3+ version did not do the trick]

Comment: This worked for me, using ubuntu 13.10 and eclipse kepler. also added the goto links at the bottom.

Comment: I'm now back on a Ubuntu workstation and can confirm that this adds the formatting. The background is still black though, **[see my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043778/722929)** for description on how to solve this

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore (Luna, ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: If installing libwebkitgtk do not work, see if you have this config in eclipse.ini : -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla. Try commenting out this line. HTML in javadoc came back for me after doing that.

Comment: Works in debian-jessie too.

Comment: With Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu Vivid I had to install `libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25` to get the rendering of tool tips and Javadoc right.

Comment: So it's STILL not listed as a dependency? Well, thank you @Moritz for the update!

Comment: Johannes, I don't know if it's listed as a dependency. I didn't install Eclipse from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Gotcha. ANybody who did?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out this is caused by two problems:

1. Eclipse needs webkitgtk
2. Eclipse color scheme is messed up on ubuntu.

The solution is thus two-fold.

### Part 1: Install webkitgtk

Just run this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get -y install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

*Thanks to Johannes H. for this bit*

### Part 2: Update the color scheme

First create a new configuration in your home directory.

```
gedit ~/.gtkrc-eclipse
```

And paste this content:

```
# Customs color settings for Eclipse.
# Load Eclipse as follows:
# GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.gtkrc-eclipse eclipse
#
# Sources:
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043778/722929
# http://askubuntu.com/a/131348/18533
# http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/
 
# Tooltip background color.
style "eclipse-tooltips" {
bg[NORMAL] = "#f5f5b5"
fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
 
# Load settings.
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "eclipse-tooltips"
```

Find the `eclipse43.desktop` file and edit it (If you are using another version of Eclipse than 4.3 update the commands accordingly):

```
locate eclipse43.desktop
# Use the location from above
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse43.desktop
```

Find the line that starts with `Exec=...` and change it from something like this:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse43
```

to something like this

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "GTK2_RC_FILES=~/.gtkrc-eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse43"
```

**Voila, beautiful colors.** (or as beautiful as Eclipse gets)

Answer (score 3):

For the question of background color, the problem certainly comes from the GTK settings.

You should get a solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

Comment: I suppose this is not possible to fix it elsewhere than into the GTK settings too.
Otherwise, you have the Javadoc view but you may already know it, aren't you ? And maybe, the problem is the same with that view...

Comment: also see this ans for background color in ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467359/how-to-change-the-textcolor-of-the-javadoc-view-in-eclipse/26679470#26679470

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Mars methods with GTK2 don't work anymore. You should only edit `usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` section with name `/*default color scheme */`. Change `@define-color tooltip_bg_color` and `@define-color tooltip_fg_color` for your favorite color.

Comment: I try new LiClipse on xubuntu 15.10 and i can edit this colour on that file `/usr/share/themes/Graybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`. I don't know why it use gtk-2.0, but this can help, if first method not working for you.