# Eclipse Javadoc not rendering correctly

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I'm currently trying to set up my working environment in Ubuntu 12.10, and I'm currently lost with the styling of Javadoc in Eclipse. The tooltips, and the Javadoc shown in the Javadoc perspective are not rendering the HTML correctly at all.
This is what it looks like on my Windows 7 installation of Eclipse:
[image: Javadoc Perspective Win7]

On Ubuntu, it looks completely broken and is not rendering anything correctly, which gets especially distracting when there is lots of text, code or other things included into the Javadoc:
[image: Javadoc Perspective Ubuntu]

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue before or might be able to help otherwise?
Note: I also changed my gtkrc up a bit to change the tooltip color, as it used to be just really dark text on black background, but that should have only changed the general font and background color, not the rendering of HTML.

I just found this very related question:
[Eclipse is formatting javadoc tooltips very poorly on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926774/eclipse-is-formatting-javadoc-tooltips-very-poorly-on-ubuntu?rq=1)

However, noone there was able to answer the person asking the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem- Solution is easy: Install the libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 package available in the default ubuntu repositories.

(If you're not using Ubuntu find out how that component is called on your distro and how to install it)

Comment: Thanks! It had actually fixed itself at some point, and I wondered what happened. Apparently someting installed libwebkitgtk as a dependency, and that caused it to work.

Comment: It should really be a dependency for eclipse itself, at least "recommended", if not "required".