# Eclipse Javadoc not showing HTML table correctly

Tags: linux, eclipse, javadoc

[image: Screenshot]

I'm having trouble displaying HTML correctly in the Javadoc editor in Eclipse. It also isn't shown correctly if I hover over the method name.

I read previous StackOverflow threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491296/eclipse-javadoc-not-rendering-correctly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926774/eclipse-is-formatting-javadoc-tooltips-very-poorly-on-ubuntu?rq=1) which both have answers stating you should install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 and libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 but I already have both of those installed.

I am using Linux Mint and Eclipse Kepler Release 2. The javadoc table displays as expected on my Windows machine.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how this can be resolved?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 14.04.  I've never had to install anything special to get tables to display correctly.  However... and this is just a hunch... I've never used `thead` and `tbody` tags, just `tr`, `th`, and `td`.  See if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't help either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `<table></table>` element, insert `border="1"` so that it shows up. That worked for me.

`<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Value 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Value 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>`